# jquery can't hide parent with button within

Tags: jquery

I am working on a jquery issue where I can't hide a div using a button within it. See this fiddle for an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/EfnND/27/

Is this a limitation of jquery? I'm at a loss as to why the ID returned is correct (and if you explicitly hide the ID in the js console it works!), but when Cancel is clicked nothing happens.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you click on cancel, it also triggers the hide graph event since it is in the same container. Using stopPropagation() you can cancel the bubbling effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/EfnND/35/

Comment out the stopPropagation() line to see in the console that it hides and shows simultaneously when you click cancel.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `return false` from the click event handler (to close the parent) and then show the sibling: http://jsfiddle.net/EfnND/55/

Comment: Hey thanks for the parent().siblings() line; I had to favor Jason's answer for its use of stopPropagation(), but it was a tough call.